# Rename factor changes all rows to NA

Tags: r

I have a column TIME with these values:

```
Time=0.15,Time=0.7,Time=0.9
```

I want to change this to:

```
10,20,40
```

I try to do it like this:

```
data$TIME <- factor(data$TIME, 
                            levels=c("Time=0.15","Time=0.7","Time=0.9", 
                            labels=c(10, 20, 40))
```

But this gives me (checked with `str()`):

```
$ TIME       : Factor w/ 15 levels "10","20","30",..: NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

How come? Any suggestions?

EDIT:

dputs(data$TIME) gives (and str(data) tells me that time is a character type of data):

```
## c("Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.15.h", 
## "Time.0.15.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
## "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", "Time.0.3.h", 
...
...
...
```

EDIT:

TESTING:

```
data$TIME <- factor(data$TIME, 
                            levels = c("Time.0.15.h","Time.0.3.h","Time.0.5.h","Time.0.75.h","Time.1.h","Time.1.5.h","Time.2.h","Time.2.5.h","Time.3.h","Time.4.h","Time.5.h","Time.6.h","Time.8.h","Time.12.h","Time.24.h"), 
                            labels = c(10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 240, 300, 360, 480, 720, 1440))
```

BEFORE:

```
unique(data$TIME)
##  [1] "Time.0.15.h" "Time.0.3.h"  "Time.0.5.h"  "Time.0.75.h" "Time.1.h"   
##  [6] "Time.1.5.h"  "Time.2.h"    "Time.2.5.h"  "Time.3.h"    "Time.4.h"   
## [11] "Time.5.h"    "Time.6.h"    "Time.8.h"    "Time.12.h"   "Time.24.h
```

"

AFTER:

```
##  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
```

Comment: `data$TIME <- factor(data$TIME, 
                            levels=c("0.15","0.7","0.9", 
                            labels=c(10, 20, 40))` or `dput(TIME)` and paste with your question!

Comment: @Duck I added dput() values, but they are different frrom how they look in .csv file ? in file they looks like this `Time=0.15 h,Time=0.3 h,Time=0.5 h....`

Comment: I have added a possible solution to your issue. Let me know if that worked!

Comment: @Duck Checking, will get back to you soon. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, let me know how that goes!

Comment: @Duck is it possible to open chat? I want to ask something and do not want to spam the forum ?

Comment: Sure, invite me to chat!

Comment: You never added the utput of `dput(unique(data$Time))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#Code
data$TIME <- as.character(factor(data$TIME, 
                            levels = c("Time.0.15.h","Time.0.3.h","Time.0.5.h","Time.0.75.h","Time.1.h","Time.1.5.h","Time.2.h","Time.2.5.h","Time.3.h","Time.4.h","Time.5.h","Time.6.h","Time.8.h","Time.12.h","Time.24.h"), 
                            labels = c(10, 20, 30, 45, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 240, 300, 360, 480, 720, 1440)))
```

Comment: Please check my edit wtih the results of trying the code above

Comment: @Carlton I have updated the code, please check or invite me to chat!